# How see 0 instead of (0.*10^-4)?

Tags: approximation, numerical-value

I have this:

```
deltaLAB = {-0.00079044, -0.00093133, -0.00104750, -0.00082373, \
-0.00049044, -0.00010956, -0.00044090, -0.00015910, -0.00044090, \
-0.00020864, -0.00007627, -0.00052373, -0.00007627, -0.00052373, \
-0.00014585, 0.00001982, 0.00016071, 0.00009453, -0.00012920};
SetAccuracy[deltaLAB, 2]
```

and I get this:

```
{0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-3, 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-4,
  0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-5, 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-5, 
 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-5, 0.*10^-4, 0.*10^-5, 0.*10^-4}
```

How see only 0 instead of (0.*10^-4)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use Chop. For Example : Chop[deltaLAB, 10^-2]

Comment: Or `Threshold`.

Comment: Note `Chop` will give the integer `0` and `Threshold` will give the machine real `0.`.  For data, `Threshold` is probably better since it will keep a packed real array both packed and real.

Comment: Related: [94907](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94907) , [125324](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125324). Given the alternatives discussed in this comments, probably this question deserves a canonical answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Round` to get 0 only

Comment: This works only if all the numbers are close to zero, in which case one could just multiply by `0` to get an array of zeros. If not all the numbers are close to zero, then some will have their values changed as well.